# Tablesorter works but doesn't sort correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I retrieve a list of objects sorted by name from the database and display them in a table like this

[image: List of Objects ordered by name]

and I have a html link to sort them according to last modified date and It works.
This is the link

```
        $('#sort-date-added').click(function () {
        var sorting = [[3, 1]];
        $("#products-table-mine").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
        return false;
    });
```

and I have another link to order them again by Name but when I click on the link it order them in a weird way, Its supposed to order them based on the first arrangement which is coming from the database correctly but instead it show me this order

[image: When click on sort by name it should be like the first]

and this is the function to sort them by name

```
        $('#sort-a-z').click(function () {
        var sorting = [[0, 0]];
        $("#products-table-mine").trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: After you add the data to the table from the database, are you using the update method? `$('#products-table-mine').trigger('update');`